# Is the Type MultipartFile in Spring Boot used as RequestParam or RequestBody in a PostMapping?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, post, backend

I want to use MultpartFile in a @PostMapping but I dont know if I used used it as a RequestParam or RequestBody!

I tried both but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```java
@PostMapping("/images")
public String saveAdvertisementImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile image) {
   // your logic
}
```